# How do you use Firebase within a custom class?

Tags: swift, class, firebase, appdelegate

I went through the steps to set up Firebase on my app and it tested well. But when I created a custom swift class to make functions to manage the database, it crashes and says "failed to get default firdatabase instance. must call firapp.configure() before using firdatabase". I called configure() in the AppDelegate but it doesn't seem to be passing through to my custom class. Below is the error I get, my part of the AppDelegate where i called FirebaseApp.configure(), and the custom class. Thanks in advance.

DatabaseTestApp[7814:336288] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default FIRDatabase instance. Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase.'

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
    }
}
```

my custom class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
class FirebaseClass
{
    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    init ()
    {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat and your code so that people can help you. One can't help others with proper information

Comment: Hi UmarZaii, I edited my post to show all of that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating some sort of class called FirebaseManager, do the following:

```
class FirebaseManager {
    public static let instance = FirebaseManager()
    private init(){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
}
```

Comment: That is correct, and I thought that too, but since it can only be configured once (it crashes if you try to configure it again), if init is called a second time (which it will be), it crashes.

Comment: You should consider using a Singleton for the Firebase class then, or potentially just a static instance variable within the class that you access every time instead of through the initialiser. I’ve modified my solution to reflect this

Comment: Using a singleton class worked! Thank you so much Jay.